# Form validation in model

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-core, model

I'm in a .Net Core MVC learning-by-doing process trying to do form validation in the model but it's not working as expected.

In the model:

```
namespace VPV.Models {
    public class Event : IValidatableObject {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Feltet 'Start' er obligatorisk")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Der er ikke angivet en gyldig 'Start'")]
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

On the form:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
```

and:

```
<input asp-for="Event.StartDateTime" type="text" class="form-input fv-req" />
```

The problem is, that if I leave the StartDateTime field empty, the error message on the screen is "The value '' is invalid" and not the one I typed in the model.

Also, when typing an invalid datetime value in the field, the error message is "The value '15/11/2019 09.81' is not valid for StartDateTime" - again I'd like my own error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using the class you defined these validationrules in as the model for the view, right? And did you reference the right JS libraries? Have a look at the [Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details of my code.

Right now in the testing/learning phase I'm only doing server-side validation. Is the JS required?

I've read the Model Validation documentation. Am I missing something important in my code?

Again, the validation works, but not with my own error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime type has a default value. That is why the required attribute is not triggering. What I always do is if I'm expecting a property to be null or empty, I make it nullable.

Ex.

```
DateTime? StartDateTime
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped for the empty field part. Thanks! Still I get the default invalid-error "The value '15/11/2019 09.81' is not valid for StartDateTime." and not my own. Can you help with that too?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it seems that others are also experiencing this problem. I saw someone made a custom validation on their dates. Check this link out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277814/1362850. It might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. Happy to see, that it's not just me who's having the problem. :)